# what does column attribute inside the 'many to many' tag refer to?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-mapping

What does the `column` attribute mean inside the `many to many` tag ?

```
<class name="pojo.Person" table="person">
      <id column="p_id" name="personID">
          <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
      <property name="personName" column="p_name" />
      <set name="addressSet" table="address">
          <key column="a_id" />
          <many-to-many class="pojo.Address" column="xyz" />
      </set>
</class>

<class name="pojo.Address" table="address">
      <id column="a_id" name="addressID">
          <generator class="foreign" />
      </id>
      <property name="address" column="a_id" />
</class>
```

What column does it refer to ?

What I understand from this mapping is, that `person` and `address` class have many to many relation between them.

Answer (score 0):

> The  element is the column in the address table that holds the
>   foreign key to the parent object ie. table person and links to the xyz
>   in the person table.

So you need to tell what foreign key in your child table maps to which column in the parent table as primary key.

Answer (score 0):

The column refers to foreign key on join table. Have a look at this [tutorial](http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/hibernate-many-to-many-relationship-example/), it will give you complete idea. By the way table attribute on set should be different like tableA_tableB.

Answer (score 0):

there should be a intermediate table inbetween those two tables for example

```
<class name="pojo.Person" table="person">
      <id column="p_id" name="personID">
          <generator class="increment" />
      </id>
      <property name="personName" column="p_name" />
      <set name="addressSet" table="map">
          <key column="p_id" />
          <many-to-many class="pojo.Address" column="a_id" />
      </set>
</class>

<class name="pojo.map" table="map">          
    <composite-id>
        <key-property name="person_ID" column="p_id"/>
        <key-property name="address_ID" column="a_id"/>
    </composite-id>
    <property name="person_ID" type="java.lang.Long" insert="false" update="false">
        <column name="p_id"/>
    </property>
    <property name="address_ID" type="java.lang.Long" insert="false" update="false">
        <column name="a_id"/>
    </property>

</class>

<class name="pojo.Address" table="address">
      <id column="a_id" name="addressID">
          <generator class="assigned"/>
      </id>
      <property name="address" column="address" />
</class>
```

and have a bean class for mapper

```
public class map{

    private long person_ID;

    private long address_ID;

    public long getPerson_ID() {
        return person_ID;
    }


    public void setPerson_ID(long person_ID) {
        this.person_ID= person_ID;
    }


    public long getAddress_ID() {
        return address_ID;
    }


    public void setAddress_ID(long address_ID) {
        this.address_ID= address_ID;
    }
}
```

here in the set

```
<set name="addressSet" table="map">
     <key column="p_id" />
     <many-to-many class="pojo.Address" column="a_id" />
</set>
```

key column

```
<key column="p_id" />
```

means "id" column in the person table and

```
<many-to-many class="pojo.Address" column="a_id" />
```

column in this is the "id" column in the address table

Answer (score -1):

column attribute  are used to link intermediate `address`.That is set.